# How to use Resources in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I want to put an exe file in my C++ program, but I don't understand how to do it.
I am using Visual Studio 2019. I know that it can be done through project resources, but I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: Why not just put it in the same directory as the 'parent' program and run it from there?  That's the usual way (and you provide your users with an installer that puts it in the right place).

Comment: The notion of resources is implementation specific. [This C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) don't mention them.

Comment: I recommend using an *installer* to add additional files, like exe's, to your deliverable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an [`.rc` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) to refer to the desired embedded `.exe` as an `RCDATA` resource, eg:

```
MYEXE RCDATA "path\to\file.exe"
```

Add the `.rc` file to your project.

The referred `.exe` file will then be compiled into your final executable.

You can then access the `MYEXE` resource at runtime using the Win32 `FindResource()`/`LoadResource()`/`LockResource()` functions, or higher-level framework equivalent.